# if user input a value in a 2d array, how do I tell user that don't put the next value in the same coordinate again?

Tags: python, arrays, 2d

The task is that we create a 2d array with five times five, so there are total of 25 positions with different coordinate, x can be represent by "A","B","C","D","E", and y can be represent by 12345, and there is a die roll for 25 timessince there are 25 positions. now, you are the user, you decide where do you want to place your random die number in one of this 5*5 position, and my problem is that if I put that value in the coordinate, and the user might be input the next random die number in the same coordinate, so how do I program to tell user that NO, this position has already put the value, please input your value in other positions.

```
from random import randint
cols,rows=5,5
arr = [[0 for i in range(cols)] for j in range(rows)]

def position(x, y) -> None:
    x_value = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E"]
    y_value = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"]
    if arr[y_value.index(y)][x_value.index(x)] == 0:
        arr[y_value.index(y)][x_value.index(x)] =r
       return arr

def show():
    for i in arr:
        print(i)

for i in range(25):
        throw = 0
        throw+=1
        r=randint(1, 6)
        show()
        print(f"this is what you got: {r}")
        x= input("X value:")
        y = input("Y value:")
        position(x,y)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from random import randint
cols,rows=5,5
arr = [[0 for i in range(cols)] for j in range(rows)]

def position(x, y) -> None:
    x_value = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E"]
    y_value = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"]
    
    while arr[y_value.index(y)][x_value.index(x)] != 0:
        x = input("Space occupied, Choose a new X value:")
        y = input("Space occupied, Choose a new Y value:")
    arr[y_value.index(y)][x_value.index(x)] = r
    
    return arr

def show():
    for i in arr:
        print(i)

for i in range(25):
        throw = 0
        throw+=1
        r=randint(1, 6)
        show()
        print(f"this is what you got: {r}")
        x= input("X value:")
        y = input("Y value:")
        position(x,y)
```

The way this works is if the chosen position is already occupied, it re-declares x and y variables to the user's input and keeps on asking until an unoccupied x and y coordinates have been entered. If the chosen spot is 0, then it won't run the loop and just change the coordinate to the random number.